# Capybara/Rspec test for more than one of a given element?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I am testing a page with a form that has two components - There are identical labeled fields in each section. With Capybara, I want to ensure that not only is there a "Name" field on the page (should have_field "Name"), but that there are, in fact, two of them.

Obviously, I can do this with xpath, but that's not the optimal solution. Is there a better way to handle this built into either Capybara or Rspec?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [within](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session%3awithin) - it works for both actions and matchers. For example:

```
within("#some_id")  { page.should_have("some content") }
within("#other_id") { page.should_have("some content") }
```

Comment: This works (in this situation), and I probably should have thought of it earlier since I've used it before. A general way to find more than one element would still be appreciated, though, rather than relying on containers that might later change. And in many cases, such as "Select up to four names below", there may be 4 fields with the same label that aren't in clearly delineated sections of their own.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, see the [docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method). For example:

```
all('a').each { |a| a[:href] }
```